# Using case in 2 fields condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I try to make this but fails.

```
CASE 
   WHEN ACTIVITY_id in ('100003') and (activity_status=1002) THEN 'Sudah' 
   ELSE 'Belum' 
END AS ISPENETAPAN
```

This is the table:

```
PERIOD_ID   WORKFLOW_ID USER_FOLIO_ID   ACTIVITY_ID ACTIVITY_STATUS PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID
2020            1       30167856        100001          1002                100004
2020            1       30167856        100002          1002                100001
2020            1       30167856        100003          1002                100002
2020            1       30167856        100004          1002                NULL
2020            1       30167856        100005          1000                100001
```

(THIS RESULT MUST BE NOT YET)

```
PERIOD_ID   WORKFLOW_ID USER_FOLIO_ID   ACTIVITY_ID ACTIVITY_STATUS PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID
2020            1       30172023        100001          1002                100004
2020            1       30172023        100002          1000                100001
2020            1       30172023        100003          1001                100002
2020            1       30172023        100004          1002                NULL
2020            1       30172023        100005          1000                100001
```

The case: I want to make a `CASE` in SQL Server where the `ACTIVITY_ID = 100003` has `ACTIVITY_STATUS = 1002` then `'DONE'`, else `'NOT YET'`

Comment: You say you try to make it, but it fails. What happens when you try, what error do you get? The 2 data sets you've provided don't apepar to be related, as neither have a column with the value `'Sudah'`or `'Belum`'.

Comment: _"The case : I want to make a CASE in SQL Server where the ACTIVITY_ID = 100003 has ACTIVITY_STATUS = 1002 then 'DONE', else 'NOT YET'"_, it's simple just `CASE WHEN ACTIVITY_ID = 100003 AND ACTIVITY_STATUS = 1002 THEN 'DONE' ELSE 'NOT YET' END`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like where you failed was considering `ACTIVITY_ID` as a Text by **putting that Apostrophy (')**

```
CASE
    WHEN (ACTIVITY_id  = 100003         -- If this is Text, put '100003', otherwise no (')
        AND ACTIVITY_STATUS  = 1002)    -- This is Numeric. The Parentheses help in the Filter Priority
            THEN 'DONE'
    ELSE 'NOT YET'
END AS ActivityResult;
```

> NB: You better put the parentheses as well to help SQL Server prioritize some calculations/filters.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from question.

```
CASE 
WHEN (activity_id = 100003 AND activity_status = 1002) THEN 'done' 
ELSE 'not yet' END
```

Comment: @Shudha, looking at the result, it seems that `activity_id` and `ACTIVITY_STATUS ` are all **numeric** and yours would fail as your treat them as text!